# ActionMode callback never calls onCreateActionMode when started in fragment's OnViewCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionmode

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class WeekdayTimesFragment @Inject constructor(viewModelFactory: SavedStateViewModelFactory.Factory)
    :Fragment(R.layout.fragment_weekday_times), WeekdayAlarmTimesAdapter.OnWeekdayAlarmTimePressed, ActionModeListener {

    private lateinit var weekdayAlarmTimesAdapter: WeekdayAlarmTimesAdapter
    private val weekdayTimesViewModel
            by viewModels<WeekdayTimesViewModel> { viewModelFactory.create(this) }
    override val actionCallback = PrimaryActionCallback(this)
    private var weekday: Int = 0
    private val isActionModeActive: Boolean
        get() = weekdayTimesViewModel.isActionModeActive
    private val numSelected: Int
        get() = weekdayTimesViewModel.selectedTimePositions.size

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        weekday = requireArguments().get("WEEKDAY") as Int
        if(isActionModeActive) { //action mode may be active prior to rotation
            startActionMode() //for some reason, starting action mode here does not work....
        }
        initRecyclerView() //will determine what recyclerview items are selected via the viewmodel
        weekdayTimesViewModel.getTimesAndAlarmsForSelectedWeekday(Weekday[weekday])
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { times->
                weekdayAlarmTimesAdapter.submitWeekdayTimes(times)
            }
    }

    override fun alarmTimePressed(wasSelected: Boolean, position: Int, time: WeekdayTime) {
        if(wasSelected) { //this item was selected prior to being selected, effectively unselecting it
            weekdayTimesViewModel.selectedTimePositions.remove(position)
        } else {
            weekdayTimesViewModel.selectedTimePositions[position] =
                Time(time.hour, time.minute, Weekday[weekday], time.alarm.alarmId, time.isDisabled, time.id)
        }

        if(numSelected == 0 && isActionModeActive) { //no more times are selected, turn off action mode
            destroyActionMode() //need to de-select recyclerview items
        } else {
            if (!isActionModeActive) {
                startActionMode()
            } else {
                actionCallback.changeTitle("$numSelected selected")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startActionMode() {
        actionCallback
            .startActionMode(
                requireView(),
                R.menu.toolbar_contextual_menu,
                "$numSelected selected")
        //fragment hosting the viewpager
        (requireParentFragment() as ActionModeListenerController).currentActionModeListener = this
        weekdayTimesViewModel.isActionModeActive = true
    }

    override fun onActionItemClick(item: MenuItem?) {
        item?.let {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.toolbar_disable_alarm-> {
                    requireContext().createGenericAlertDialog(
                        message = if(numSelected == 1) "Are you sure you want to disable this alarm?"
                        else "Are you sure you want to disable these alarms?",
                        positiveListener = { _, _ ->
                            weekdayTimesViewModel.disableSelectedTimes()
                            showUndoSnackbar(true)
                        }
                    ).show()
                }
                R.id.toolbar_delete_alarms-> {
                    requireContext().createGenericAlertDialog(
                        message = if(numSelected == 1) "Are you sure you want to delete this alarm?"
                        else "Are you sure you want to delete these alarms?",
                        positiveListener = { _, _ ->
                            weekdayTimesViewModel.deleteSelectedTimes()
                            showUndoSnackbar(false)
                        }
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //when we aren't destroying the view but need to end action mode (changing tab or after we confirm an action)
    //we may want to do specific things specific to certain listeners, e.g. de-select certain recyclerview items.
    override fun destroyActionMode() {
        actionCallback.finishActionMode()
        weekdayTimesViewModel.isActionModeActive = false
        //also un-select all of the elements that have been selected
        weekdayTimesViewModel.selectedTimePositions.clear()
        //redraw recyclerview as well
        rv_weekday_times.resetAdapterState()
    }

    private fun showUndoSnackbar(disablingTimes: Boolean){
        val message =
            if(disablingTimes) "Your alarm times have been disabled." else "Your alarm times have been deleted."
        Snackbar.make(requireView(), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("UNDO"){
            if(disablingTimes)
                weekdayTimesViewModel.restoreDisabledTimes()
            else
                weekdayTimesViewModel.restoreDeletedTimes()
        }.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
        .setAnchorView(requireActivity().bottom_nav_view).show()
    }

    //when rotating screen or navigating we can just end action mode. The state of whether we are
    //in action mode either doesn't matter (navigation) or is already persisted, along with the selected
    //items in the viewmodel(rotation)
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        actionCallback.finishActionMode()
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        weekdayAlarmTimesAdapter = WeekdayAlarmTimesAdapter(this, weekdayTimesViewModel.selectedTimePositions.keys)
        rv_weekday_times.apply {
            adapter = weekdayAlarmTimesAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        }
        weekdayAlarmTimesAdapter.selectedItems.clear()
        //clears selected items as these items no longer remain consistently for the lifecycle of the view
    }
}
```

So my ActionMode works great when I get a callback (alarmTimePressed) which is through a click listener set in the recyclerview's OnBindViewHolder. I start my ActionMode and it works great, I save whether ActionMode is active in my viewmodel, which works well upon rotation, as if it is active prior to rotation, it still remains active. As you can see in my OnViewCreated, I call startActionMode() when ActionMode is meant to be active. The problem is that when I start it from there, the onCreateActionMode callback is never called. This is strange because even after rotating, if I select an item in the RecyclerView it correctly launches ActionMode. The view I am passing to startActionMode is the same in both cases. If you need the code for PrimaryActionCallback, it's here: https://hastebin.com/vepujuhefe.m. Didn't think it was very necessary but in case you felt like it was necessary to see :). Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: And you are only starting it when it's active? Which means it can never start in the first place.

Comment: action mode goes way when the screen rotates (without me doing anything) which is why i start it up again